# Como funciona a atribuição de lista usando intervalo?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem

Estava lendo uma documentação na internet quando me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

Fiquei curioso, pois nunca tinha visto intervalos serem usados no lado esquerdo de uma atribuição (pra mim eles criavam uma sublista, e só). Um teste rápido me mostrou que esse código estava prefixando uma lista a outra:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> x[:0] = y
>>> x
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Mas continuo sem entender a lógica dos índices: por que usar `[:0]` colocou a outra lista no início? Que valores podem ser usados nesse intervalo, e o que eles significam? Há outras maneiras interessantes de se usar essa funcionalidade, além de pra prefixar?

Comment: Não conheço em Python mas já vi algumas coisas do tipo em outros linguagens, e dá para fazer uma coisas interessantes, inclusive com *strings* mutáveis. Nada que não dê para fazer de outra forma, mas simplifica.

Comment: Diferente mesmo. Se alguém se arriscar a tentar entender e adaptar, parece que tem uma explicação em inglês aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30221031/1796236

Comment: A lógica é pegar todos valores anteriores ao primeiro item da lista `x[:0]` e substituir pelo `y`, assim como `x[:1]` irá substituir o intervalo (-infinito até 1) pela lista, o funcionamento é o mesmo que `x[0] = 1` ou `x[1:] = [2, 3]`.

Comment: Essa eu também não conhecia. Me fez lembrar o [Mid$ em VB6](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O intervalo do lado esquerdo da atribuição indica que aquele intervalo (antes da mudança) vai ser substituído pelo que quer que venha depois da atribuição (que deve ser uma sequência ou um iterável)

Assim, uma atribuição a `x[:0] = ...` vai inserir os valores da expressão à direita no intervalo "entre o começo da lista, e a posição zero" - ou seja, vai colocar novos valores antes do inicial.

Uma atribuição à fatia  `[:]`  vai trocar todo o conteúdo da lista "do começo" (vazio antes do :) até "o final" (indicado por vazio depois do :) pelo conteúdo gerado na iteração da expressção da esquerda.

E inclusive há um "idioma" que é bastante usado para esvaziar uma lista já existente `inplace` - isso é, o objeto lista, que pode ter referências em outros lugares continua o mesmo, mas todos os seus elementos são removidos: basta associar um iterável vazio à todo o conteúdo da lista:

```
x[:] = []
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x
>>> id(x)
140612754938440
>>> x[:] = []
>>> y
[]
>>> id(x)
140612754938440
```

Então, `x[2] = [1,2,3]` vai simplesmente colocar uma nova lista `1,2,3` na posição 2 da lista original. Mas, `x[2:2] = [1,2,3]`está dizendo: "substitua todo o conteúdo começando na posição 2 e indo até imediatamente antes da posição 2 (ou seja, um "ponto matemático vazio antes do terceiro elemento da lista") pelos elementos da sequência `[1,2,3]`:  isso vai inserir esses três elementos na posição imediatamente anterior ao terceiro elemento. O "1" se torna o novo terceiro elemento, e todo o restante da lista é empurrado 3 posições para a frente:

```
>>> a = list(range(10,20))
>>> a
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a[2:2] = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

É diferente do método `insert` de listas ele empurra todo o restante para frente, mas coloca o seu argumento como um único elemento na posição indicada:

```
>>> a = list(range(10,20))
>>> a
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a.insert(2, [1,2,3])
>>> a
[10, 11, [1, 2, 3], 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>>
```

Há ainda uma outra forma de uso do "assignment to slices" que usa o terceiro parâmetro dos slices, o passo (step). Nesse caso porém, a lista não aumenta ou diminuí de tamanho de acordo com o tamanho do iterável: o número de elementos da atribuição tem que ser exatamente igual ao número de elementos que será substituído.

Por exemplo, "substitua cada terceiro elemento da minha lista, do começo até o fim, pela string 'fizz'":

```
a = list(range(10))
a[::3] = ["fizz"] * 4
```

**Por baixo do capô**

E isso é mágica? Não  - qualquer objeto em Python pode entregar resultados quando é acionado pelo operador de `[]` - ele só precisa que sua classe implemente o método `__getitem__` . Para aceitar atribuições usando o `x[ ] = ...`o objeto deve ser de uma classe que implemente `__setitem__`. Se vocẽolhar na documentação oficial dos métodos mágicos, em https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types - vai perceber que esses métodos são métodos normaizinhos de Python - o `__getitem__` tem uma assinatura do tipo:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
     ....
```

O que acontece quando alguém usa a notação de `:` entre colchetes é que o Python cria um objeto `slice` e o envia no lugar do `index` - o slice tem os atributos `start`, `stop` e `step` (uma omissão de número antes ou depois de um `:` coloca um `None` no atributo respectivo).

Então se você quiser emular um container type que use a notação de fatias para seus próprios fins, basta detectar objetos do tipo `slice` vindo nesses parâmetros (com `isinstance`) e responder de acordo.

**Mais usos dos índices entre colchetes**

Uma forma que não é usada na biblioteca padrão, mas que tem uso extensivo em módulos 3rd party (em particular o Numpy - a biblioteca de facto para computação científica em Python) é separar índices com uma vírgula dentro do colchetes. Isso faz com que o parâmetro index seja uma tupla de Python, e pode ser usado normalmente para indexar objetos multimensionais (o NumPy usa para matrizes).  Mais ainda, você pode usar a notação de `slices` dentro das expressões separadas por vírcula, dentro do colchetes.

Por exemplo, vamos usar o Numpy para criar uma matriz  de 5 x 5 números inteiros, preenche-la com "1" e usar a sintaxe de slices para "limpar" uma janela 3x3 no centro da matriz, com zeros. Note que ao contrário das listas de Python, o Numpy aceita um elemento não iterável do lado esquerdo de uma atribuição com slices: ele coloca aquele elemento em todas as posiçoes descritas.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=np.uint32)
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint32)
>>> a[:] = 5
>>> a
array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=uint32)
```

E para o exemplo da "janela":

```
>>> a = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.uint32)
>>> a[:, :] = 1
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint32)
>>> a[1:4, 1:4] = 0
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint32)
```

**Também quero!**

Se você quiser experimentar brincar com índices, basta implementar sua própria classe com `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` e `__delitem__` - você tanto pode criar uma subclasse de `list` como criar seu iterador do zero. Criar uma subclasse de `list` diretamente tem algumas contra-indicações: o Python tem algumas otimizações internas que podem fazer com que nem todos os métodos especiais  (os que tem `__nomeassim__` ) sejam chamados para todas as operações conforme se espera.  Para isso existe a classe `collections.UserList` (`from UserList import UserList` em Python2) na biblioteca padrão. Ela se comporta exatamente como uma lista, mas é feita para ser herdada. Para criar do zero, herde uma classe de `collections.abc.MutableSequence` e implemente os respectivos métodos descritos em https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html - (`collections.MutableSequence` em Python 2.x - sem o `abc`).

Então para ter uma lista que ao receber uma fatia simplesmente insira o valor da expressão à direita em todas as posições da fatia, sem tentar iterar o objeto, basta fazer:

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            start = index.start if index.start is not None else 0
            stop = index.stop if index.stop is not None else len(self)
            step = index.step if index.step is not None else 1
            for i in range(start, stop, step):
                 self[i] = value
            return
        super().__setitem__(index, value)
```

E assim:

```
>>> a = MyList(range(10))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[::3] = "fizz"
0 10 3
>>> a
['fizz', 1, 2, 'fizz', 4, 5, 'fizz', 7, 8, 'fizz']
>>>
```

(Para uma lista normal, `fizz` seria tratado como um iterável, e cada letra seria usada em um lugar - o resultado seria: `['f', 1, 2, 'i', 4, 5, 'z', 7, 8, 'z']`)