# Uso do carácter dois pontos ":" no Python

Tags: python, característica-linguagem

No Python existe o carácter *dois pontos* `:`, sendo assim, o que eu entendo deste carácter é que ele é usado em funções `def soma(x,y):`, comandos condicionais `if soma > 100:` e para classes `class Carro(object):`, para indicar o fim do cabeçalho e assim por diante. Entretanto, existe outro propósito para ele alem dos citados anteriormente? Caso haver outro propósito, o *dois pontos* `:` se torna algum tipo de operador?

Um pequeno exemplo prático do uso do *dois pontos* `:` para ilustração:

```
def soma(x,y):
    return x + y

x = input("Valor de x:")
y = input("Valor de y:")

soma = soma(x,y)

if soma > 100:
    print("Resultado maior que 100")
```

Comment: Slices. Não consigo lembrar outra.

Comment: em algumas outras linguagens de script como php e javascript ele pode ser usado para definir um operador tenario neste site tem um exemplo bem simples: http://aprenda-python.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/operador-ternario.html agora no python como voce disse ele indica o fim do cabecalho. no site da python brasil tem uma introducao mais elaborada sobre o assunto http://wiki.python.org.br/AspectosFormaisDaLinguagemPython

Comment: É uma pergunta bem estranha - não acho que ajuda a entender a linguagem, ficar perguntando "todos os contextos em que o caracter X" é usado. Se pegar um uso que você não entende, pergunte. Eu mesmo não me lembrei a principio do uso em dicionários e em fatias de índices (slices) - mas quando precisamos escrever essas expressões o ":" ocorre naturalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentei acima, não acho um tipo de pergunta que ajude muito - mas vamos lá, são quatro usos que estou lembrando agora, e um uso que não acontece que vale a pena mencionar:

**`:` indica o início de um bloco**. Como você apontou na pergunta, não ssó esses comandos, mas qualquer um que inicie um bloco de código tem um `:` no final da linha. Nesse sentido ele é parecido com o  `{` de C e linguagens derivadas com a diferença de que nunca é opcional: Em C (ou seus descendentes sintáticos, comoC++, Java, Javascript, PHP, C# , objective C, etc), após um comando de controle de fluxo, em geral é opcional abrir uma chave - você
pode colocar uma única expressão (terminada com `;`).

Em Python sempre é obrigatório o `:` e mais, sempre é obrigatório que na sequência venha um bloco de código com identação maior do que a da linha em que estava o `:` - mesmo que você não queria fazer nada nesse bloco (por exemplo, uma cláusula `except` e que você só queira silênciar um erro. Se quiser um bloco que não faça nada, ele deve conter o comando `pass` devidamente identado:

```
a = 0
try:
    a = valor/ valor2
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

**`:` é usado na construção de dicionários** - como bem lembrou o @IronMan em sua resposta. A sintaxe é parecida que a de dicionários de Javascript - 
`dados = {"chave": "valor", "chave2": "valor2"}`.  Diciionários também podem ser criados com a chamada direta da função embutida `dict`, usando-se a sintaxe de chamada de função com argumentos com palavra chave, que dispensa os `:`: `dados = dict(chave="valor", chave2="valor2")` - note que nesse caso, a linguagem transforma automaticamente o nome dos parâmetros passados como palavra chave em strings que serão chaves no dicionário. Usando o construtor de dicionário com `{ }`, as aspas são necessárias para indicar que as chaves são strings, e além disso as chaves podem uma grande variedade de objetos de Python, não só strings. Essas são diferenças para o dicionário de Javascript.

Mais ainda, a construção com chaves, mas com valores separados por `,`, sem pares de chave e valor, criam um outro objeto em Python: os conjuntos (sets):
`meu_conjunto = {"dado1", "dado2", "dado3"}`. É um tipo de objeto bem diferente de um dicionário que só tem em comum com o mesmo o algorítmo para saber se um determinado item faz parte do mesmo ou não (no caso do Python a continência é em relação as chaves, não aos valores).

**`:` serve para declarar "fatias" (slices)**, como lembrou o @Pablo, ao recuperar items de sequências. Praticamente qualquer linguagem moderna permite que se recupere um único item de uma sequência com um número entre colchetes. `a = "overflow"; a[0]; -> 'o'` - mas Python permite que você especifique `[inicio:fim]` dentro dos colchetes  `a = "overflow"; a[1:5]; -> 'verf'`, ou  `[inicion:fim:passo]`. Ainda esta semana expliquei bem como fatias funcionam nesta outra resposta: [Como funciona a atribuição de lista usando intervalo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110054/como-funciona-a-atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-lista-usando-intervalo/110256#110256)

**`:` pode criar anotações sobre parâmetros de uma função** em Python 3.x, de forma *opcional*.

Python é uma linguagem dinâmica, e qualquer parâmetro ou variável sempre fazer referência a qualquer tipo de objeto. No entanto, muitas vezes em sistemas grandes, frameworks, metodologias de trabalho, ou para ajudar ferramentas de teste estático e mesmo IDEs pode ajudar você ter alguma informação sobre o tipo de dados que um parâmetro deveria ser, ou que tipo de parâmetros deveria retornar. Em Python 3 criaram uma sintaxe para "anotations" -

Normalmente declaramos uma função assim:

```
>>> def soma2(a, b):
...     return a + b
...
```

Mas pode ser feito assim:

```
>>> def soma(a: int, b: int) -> int:
...     return a + b
...
```

Essa sintaxe não faz nada por si, só cria uma função quer tem como um de seus atributos um dicionário de nome `__annotations__`, que armazena as informações colocadas na criação da função:

```
>>> soma.__annotations__
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```

Essa sintaxe é válida desde Python 3.0, em 2008 - mas não faz nada, nem modifica nenhum comportamento - e os valores depois do `:` não precisam ser classes, podem ser qualquer expressão válida. Isso não impede que o programador crie um decorador, ou outra forma de analisar o código tanto antes do uso, quanto em tempo de execução para fazer coisas com esses valores anotados. Mas foi somente em 2015, com a PEP 484, que a linguagem declarou uma forma preferencial de usar essas anotações, e ferramentas que auxiliam ou se beneficiam desse uso. [Confira a PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) que fala disso.

É desnecessário dizer que enquanto os três primeiros usos de `:` fazem parte do dia a dia de qualquer programador iniciante ou fluente em Python, esse quarto tipo tem uso ainda incipiente e você dificilmente vai encontrar código que use essas marcações. É possível que alguns projetos de grande porte, ou trabalho interno de times, comece a usar anotações depois da PEP 484, em código feito a partir deste ano.

**`:` não funcionam**, por fim,  como lembrou o @ ӝ nos comentários, como parte do operador ternário de `if`, como acontece nas linguagens derivadas de `C`. Em C e descententes, funciona: `condicao? valor1: valor2` - a expressão em condição é avaliada - se for verdadeira, a expressão toda vale `valor1`, senão é usado `valor2`. Em Python, esse `if` como expressão é escrito por extenso, de uma forma que lembra a linguagem falada: 
`valor1 if condicao else valor2`  - nesse caso, a expressão "valor1", como no "?:" de C, só é avaliada se a condição for verdadeira - senão é avaliada a expressão em "valor2".

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou a entender outras características da linguagem que eu nem sabia, e que  sera útil no meu dia dia, tenho certeza que qualquer iniciante em programação e ainda mais em Python, vai aprender com a pergunta e as resposta dela, já que as [pesquisas](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Uso+do+dois+pontos+%3A+python&oq=Uso+do+dois+pontos+%3A+python&gs_l=serp.3...18529.25003.0.25376.27.27.0.0.0.0.482.4536.0j10j7j1j1.19.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.16.3795.4fkqP-ryp1A) que fiz referente ao `:`  no Python não retornavam resultados concretos. Obrigado :D

Answer (score 2):

O operador `:` também é utilizado na construção de Dicionários ou Dictionary.
Dicionários usam o conceito de tabelas de hash, em que cada valor tem uma chave que pode ser uma String, uma tupla ou qualquer coisa que seja imutável. As chaves são separadas dos valores por `:`

Exemplo:

```
dic_pessoa = {"nome":"zézinho","Idade":10,"Cidade":"Patopólis"};
print(dic_pessoa['nome']); #imprime 'zézinho'
```

Answer (score 2):

O caracter `:` indica que vamos iniciar um sub-bloco de código.
O equivalente a `{` em Javascript e Java.

As linhas seguintes deverão estar indentadas.
É usado na declarações de funções `def`, de classes, instruções `if`, `for`, etc.

De notar que é permitido (apesar de não conforme com [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) que um sub-bloco de uma só linha seja escrito na mesma linha de código .
Usando o seu exemplo, poderíamos também escrever.

```
if soma > 100: print("Resultado maior que 100")
```