# Utilização dos dois pontos em atribuição de variável

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Estou utilizando o Python para conectar no Redshift da AWS. Fui usar a documentação do `redshift_connector` e me deparei com o código abaixo:

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    database='dev',
    user='awsuser',
    password='my_password'
 )

cursor: redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Não entendo a última linha `cursor: redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()`, especificamente a utilização dos dois-pontos.

Consultei [esse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111289/uso-do-car%C3%A1cter-dois-pontos-no-python), mas ele não comenta sobre esse uso específico.

Answer (score 3):

O caractere `:` tem algumas funções diferentes dependendo do contexto, mas nesse seu exemplo ele serve pra fazer a **tipagem** (em inglês: *type hinting*) de uma variável.

#### Como funciona?

Em Python, a tipagem de uma variável é feita da seguinte forma:

```
var: type = value
```

Traduzindo: a variável `var`, que foi associada ao valor `value`, é do tipo de dado `type`.

Alguns exemplos concretos:

```
a: int = 1
b: float = 3.2
c: str = 'Hello'
```

#### Pra quê serve?

A tipagem em Python é 100% opcional e documentativa, ou seja, você nunca é obrigado a usá-la e ela serve apenas para lhe ajudar a entender o código. No seu exemplo, mesmo que eu não conheça nada da biblioteca utilizada, só de ler a linha eu já entendo que a variável `cursor` representa um objeto do tipo `redshift_connector.Cursor`. Pode parecer algo "bobo", mas em projetos grandes esse tipo de informação facilita *muito* a sua vida, além de poder ser interpretado por alguns programas de escrita de código (mais detalhes abaixo).

É claro que nada impede você de criar uma tipagem errada - Python **nunca, jamais** checa o tipo de variáveis sem que você peça por isso. O código abaixo é perfeitamente válido do ponto de vista do interpretador de Python, apesar de apresentar uma tipagem errada:

```
a: str = 10
b: list = 20
c: dict = a + b
```

As variáveis `a`, `b` e `c` são todas do tipo `int`, mas o código executa de qualquer forma, sem nenhum tipo de conferência.

#### Onde mais posso usar?

Também é possível adicionar a tipagem a funções em Python, ex:

```
def tamanho_do_string(s: str) -> int:
    """Retorna o tamanho (número de caracteres) do string s."""
    return len(s)
```

Neste caso, estou deixando claro a todos os leitores da função que ela aceita um `str` como argumento, e retorna um `int`. Novamente, o Python nunca checa se isso é verdade ou não durante a execução do programa - a tipagem serve apenas para informar os leitores do código.

Outra vantagem é que alguns editores de texto e IDEs são capazes de usar a informação da tipagem para lhe dar avisos e chamar a atenção de erros lógicos enquanto você escreve o código. Por exemplo, tendo a função acima tipada, se eu escrever:

```
n = tamanho_do_string('abcde')
n + 'fghi'
```

Em programas que suportam a **checagem de tipo** (em inglês: *type checking*), a segunda linha será marcada como um *warning* que me avisa do erro lógico: não posso somar um `int` (retornado da função `tamanho_do_string`) a um `str`.