# Por que a lista mostra os dois primeiros elementos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Declaração de uma lista

```
>>> convites = ['Flavio Almeida', 'Nico Steppat', 'Romulo Henrique']
```

quando vai mostrar, aparece assim

```
>>> convites[0]
'Flavio Almeida'
>>> convites[1]
'Nico Steppat'
>>> convites[2]
'Romulo Henrique'
```

acredito que esteja correto, por causa disso;

```
posição           0                 1                2
>>> convites = ['Flavio Almeida', 'Nico Steppat', 'Romulo Henrique']
```

porque Flavio está na posição 0, Nico está posição 1 e Romulo na posição 2

porque na hora de imprimir duas posições ele se comporta de maneira diferente, como mostra abaixo?

```
>>> convites[0:2]
['Flavio Henrique', 'Nico Steppat']
```

Ao meu entender deveria ser

```
['Flavio Henrique', 'Romulo Henrique']
```

Eu não entendi, alguém pode me explicar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando diz

```
>>> convites[0:2]
```

está dizendo: à partir do elemento 0 de `convites`, vá até o elemento que antecede o elemento 2.

Ele não está dizendo: pegue o elemento 0 e 2.

Ali não é uma lista e sim uma faixa de dados contínua, você não pode selecionar quais elementos deseja e sim onde começa e onde termina a faixa desejada. O que vem antes dos dois pontos é onde deve começar a faixa e o que vem depois é o elemento onde já não pertence mais à faixa. Então no seu exemplo:

```
posição          0                 1               2
>>> convites = ['Flavio Almeida', 'Nico Steppat', 'Romulo Henrique']
```

Começou em 0 e foi até o 1 já que o 2 é o primeiro a ser excluído do que se pretende.

Comment: Outra opção ainda melhor para não ter que setar na mão é usar:
convites[:len(convites)] de 0 até o número de elementos, já que o index inicia sempre em 0 o número de elementos é sempre index+1.

Answer (score 4):

O sistema de `slices` - fatias do Python funciona de forma intuitiva, e até hoje a melhor forma que encontrei de explicar como funciona é fazer analogia com uma regua.

Imagine que você tem uma regua, em centimetros, e coloque um item, como um botão de camisa, em cada centimetro da regua: Se você disser "pegue o botão na posição 0" - ele vai pegar o botão que está no primeiro centimetro da regua - entre o número 0 e o número 1.

Quando você usa os ":" para criar uma fatia, é isso que está dizendo, com `[0:2]`: me pegue os items da posição "0 até a posição 2".

Note que fica interessante por que se você quer continuar pegando items na mesma lista, continua no número de onde parou, e não tem que ficar fazendo malabarismos de subtrair (ou somar) 1 ao item final da fatia anterior.

Com uma lista numérica pra ficar mais simples dá para ver isso bem.

```
>>> a = list(range(10, 20))
>>> a
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a[0:3]
[10, 11, 12]
>>> a[3:6]
[13, 14, 15]
>>> a[6:9]
[16, 17, 18]
>>> a[9:]
[19]
```

Depois que entender essa parte, de uma olhada numa outra resposta minha onde analizo aspectos mais avançados do sistema de fatias usado no Python:

[Como funciona a atribuição de lista usando intervalo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110054/como-funciona-a-atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-lista-usando-intervalo/110256#110256)