# Como ter dois contadores no mesmo laço de repetição?

Tags: python

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu código:

```
for c in range(0, len(str(ListaTemp[4]))):
    for c2 in range(c+1, len(str(ListaTemp[4]))):
        if str(num)[c] == str(num)[c2]:
            valido = True
```

E assim. Meu professor vai dar uma notinha a mais pra quem fizer o menor código. Eu me lembro vagamente de ter visto algo tipo:

```
for c, c2 in range(0, 10):
```

Nessa parte do código, eu preciso verificar se não existem elementos repetidos numa *string*. então não posso simplesmente colocar o `c+1`, pois ocorre um erro.

Então gostaria de saber se isso é realmente possível.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [dois contadores no for? Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306866/dois-contadores-no-for-python)

Comment: Você pode postar o código completo?

Comment: kkk é complicado postar ele todo aqui... porque algum coleguinha pode ver e copiar algo. Depois de entregar pro professor, ai não tem problema kkkk. Mas então. essa parte não se relaciona diretamente com as outras (apenas no final). nela chega uma variavel do tipo inteiro(por isso converto pra string ali. para poder utilizar o índice). tudo o que preciso, é verificar se existem dígitos iguais na string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar *slices* para acessar partes da *string* em conjunto com a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
texto = 'Stack Overflow em Português'

for a, b in zip(texto, texto[1:]):
    if a == b:
        print('Há caracteres iguais em sequência')
        break
else:
    print('Não há caracteres iguais em sequência')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TangibleOlivedrabBlockchain) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6pjvmJ)</sup>

Leituras adicionais:

- [Como funciona a atribuição de lista usando intervalo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110054/5878)
- [Existe alguma maneira pythônico de fazer "slice" de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265066/5878)
- ["[-4:]" O que é essa sintaxe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96604/5878)
- [Por que a lista mostra os dois primeiros elementos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114106/5878)
- [Uso do carácter dois pontos ":" no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111289/5878)

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 2):

Em Python é possível que um comando `for` percorra sim várias sequências ao mesmo tempo.

Mas, antes de dizer iss, melhor esclarecer algumas coisas: (1) o `for` em Python não é, em geral, usado para "contadores". Já que o `for` sempre vai percorrer uma sequência, o natural é o comando percorrer cada elemento de uma sequência, não o índice do elemento (para depois, dado o índice, extrair o elemento da sequência). Em outras linguagens essa construção em geral leva o nome de "for each":

```
for letra in "palavra":
   print(letra)
```

em vez de:

```
for i in range(len("palavra")):
   letra = "palavra"[i]
   print(letra)
```

E (2): poder "ver" ao mesmo tempo uma letra e a letra seguinte não vai te ajudar com esse problema da questão em particular - você vai precisar de dois `for` um dentro do outro mesmo.

Então, em Python, o comando `for` usa o elemento sobre o qual vai interagir como um "iterador". Ou seja, `for item in minhalista:` vai chamar o equivalente a `iter(minhalista)`, e no objeto (vamos chamar de ITER) retornado por isso, vai fazer o equivalente a `next(ITER)`. Quando a chamada ao `next` falhar (com uma exeção interna de "StopIteration") o for é encerrado.

Se o iterador usado no `for` retornar uma sequência, os valores retornados pela sequência são distribuidos para as variáveis do `for`.

No caso mais simples, se eu tiver:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
for b, c in a:
   print(b, c)
```

O laço vai se repetir 3 vezes e a cada vez um item da sequência interna vai estar em b, e o outro em c.

No caso de sequências, se você quer combinar elementos das mesmas no `for`, há a chamada conveniente `zip`- que pega um elemento de cada sequência e entrega de forma que pode ser usado no for:

```
a = range(10)
b = range(10, 20)

for c, d in zip(a, b):
   print(c,d)
```

No caso de uma string, se desejar pegar sempre uma letra e a próxima letra é possível fazer:

```
a = "meu texto"
for letra1, letra2 in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print(letra1, letra2)
```

(`a[1:]`  é simplesmetne a string em `a` a partir da letra de índice "1" até o final, ou seja, se a string for "palavra", na primeira interação serão usadas as letras "p" e "a")

E, explicado como funciona em Python - para o seu problema você vai precisar de simplesmente:

```
for letra1 in "palavra":
   for letra2 in "palavra":
      # coparações e atribuições necessárias para detectar repetição.
```

Você pode precisar também do `enumerate`, um outro built-in do Python que além de cada elemento de uma sequência você recebe o índice do mesmo:

```
for i, letra1 in enumerate("palavra):
   for letra2 in "palavra"[i:]:
       # codigo
```

Comment: No último exemplo existirá o fator de considerar a mesma letra em ambos os laços, podendo gerar um resultado inesperado, não?

Comment: aí é o algoritmo dela que tem que cuidar - mas sim, faz sentido usar o enumerate para ter o índice da letra também.